# parameter not picked up by search cursor in nested loop

Tags: python, loops, arcpy

Python doesn't recognize my parameter (`row`) in the second  search cursor.

I used two layers in arcmap. The first is the boroughs and the second is the roads that already comes with the Borogh field, where he is located.

```
   cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor('London_Borough_Excluding_MHW', ["NAME"])
 length = 0
 delimit = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters('London_Borough_Excluding_MHW',["NAME"])
 >>> for row in cursor:
 ...     name = row[0]

 ...     cursor2 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Join_roads_sorted",["LENGTH_GEO"],"\"NAME_1\"= 'name'")
 ...     for row2 in cursor2:
 ...         length = length + row2[0] 
 ...     print length
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the `name` variable from the first cursor as part of the SQL query on the second cursor?

Comment: yes, exactly. i seek the length of the roads in every borogh

Comment: Your current syntax isn't passing the variable `name`but rather a string 'name'. Try building the query string then passing it when you create `cursor2`:

`query = '"NAME_1" = \'{}\''.format(name)`
`cursor2 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Join_roads_sorted",["LENGTH_GEO"], query)`